# system of ODE with non-constant args using scipy.odeint

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I have a system of ODE with some parameters, let's call them a,b and c. At this moment they are only variable, so I use this code to compute my equations :

```
def fct(y, t, a, b, c) : 
    ydot[1] = ..
    ydot[2] = ..
    return ydot
```

To solve it I call it like that :

```
solution = odeint(fct, yinit, t, args = (a,b,c,))
```

and it works great, but now I have the same variable 'a' that evolve with time but I don't have a function a(t) for it, just a vector of value. I just want to implement an array (size of t obviously) which contains the evolving value of 'a'

```
a = np.zeros((len(t),1)) # of course it's not full of zeros in my programm
```

Is it possible using these libraries ?

Comment: **that evolve with time but is not a function of time**, that's a new one on me. Without seeing your equations I cant really answer your question

Comment: Oh yes, by rereading it I got your point. I Just wanted to say that I don't have a function a(t), just values in an array

Comment: You'll need to create a function a(t), perhaps by using an interpolator from [`scipy.interpolate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) based on your known values.